# Jenkins docker agent pipeline without root

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkinsfile with a very basic pipeline that spins up a docker container:

```
pipeline {

  agent { dockerfile { args '-u root' } }

  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        echo 'Testing...'
        sh 'whoami'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the app I have setup inside my container is configured in such a way that it must run as it's own user, running as root will cause the application to fail on startup. If I change my args to `args '-u foo'`, I get errors after the container is built:

`/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/*/*/jenkins-log.txt permission denied`

This path is exists inside both the container and the jenkins server. I am having issues with the path inside the container. One of the files saved in that location is also a `scripts.sh` - jenkins transcribes all the sh commands in the pipeline to that file and runs that file.

That puts me in a difficult spot - it seems as if Jenkins requires the container to be run as root to actually send any commands, or interact with anything inside the container, but the container will not build correctly unless I use `foo`.

Does anyone have any ideas on a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that on linux machines docker mostly runs as root. Docker needs te run as root otherwise it will have trouble with networking and stuff. So your docker container is run by a root process and all files created will be created by the "root" enabled container.

Jenkins though mostly does not run as root and has therefore no rights to delete these files.

Possible solution:

- Make sure that the files created in the volume (to local jenkins drive) have rights assigned to them that jenkins can work with

Hope I interpreted your question correctly and it helps...

Comment: The user permissions I'm referencing are actually all inside the container.

You can see what I'm talking about if you startup a node with a super basic dockerfile as root and put an `sh 'wait 5m'` command in the stage step. If you run `docker exec *name* ls -al /var/lib/jenkins` you'll see that location inside the container; and only root has rights by default.

Comment: where does the `jenkins-log.txt` reside then inside or outside the container? can you make your question more specific by editing it?

Comment: It always exists in the path that I gave - the `*/*` is in the path because that changes based on the name of the jenkins pipeline name and the id of the build.

I added some extra details, I hope that helps.